# Adding elements to xml from a list

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a problem, and i cant figure out what is the matter. I want to insert elements to my XML file from a listbox. In the listbox there are Menuelem elements, which has a string and an int variable.

```
    dt = DateTime.Now;
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

    XElement user = new XElement("user", new XAttribute("id", id),
                        new XElement("order", new XAttribute("id", key),
                            new XElement("date", dt.ToString()))
                    );
    doc.Element("orders").Add(user);
    doc.Save(path);
    foreach (Menuelem item in listBox6.Items)
    {
        int j=0;
        var menuelem = new XElement("menuelem", new XAttribute("db", j),
                       new XElement("name", item.Nev),
                       new XElement("price", item.Ar));
        doc.Element("order").Add(menuelem); //throws nullreferenceexception
        doc.Save(path);
        j++;
    }

    listBox6.Items.Clear();
    label3.Text = "";
    key++;

}
```

What I want to look my XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<orders>
 <user id="0">
  <order id="0">
   <date>2012.11.19. 2:16:12</date>
   <menuelem db = "0">
    <name>asdasdas</name>
    <price>1000</price>
   <menuelem db = "1">
    <name>asds</name>
    <price>2000</price>
  </order>
 <user id="0">
  <order id="1">
    <date>2012.11.19. 2:16:15</date>
    <menuelem db = "0">
      <name>asdasdas</name>
      <price>1000</price>
    <menuelem db = "1">
      <name>asds</name>
      <price>2000</price>
   </order>
 </user>
</orders>
```

Can anyone solve this using linq?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You code tries to find "order" element as immediate child of the document which contains only root element ("orders") and as result getting `null`. See [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) for details on what it searches for elements and when returns `null`.

You need to correctly select your newly inserted element. Simple option is to use [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) by name and select last one (which is the user just added by Add)

```
 doc.Descendants("order").Last().Add(menuelem);
```

Easier option is to build "user" element completely and than add it to the tree. Than you don't need to search document for nodes just added to it.

Comment: -1: If you want to read the OP's mind and address his original problem, then you're obviously incorrect. The OP wants to add the "menuitem" elements to that particular user that he just added, not to the first user that exists in the document as your solution would do.

Comment: @DanielT - Fyodor Soikin makes a good point - you should use just added user (or better yet build user completely and than add to the document).

Answer (score 0):

you got null reference because you have not "order" as root element so you need to do this

```
 XElement element =  doc.Element("orders").Element("user").Element("order");
 element.Add(menuelem);
```

if you have multiple element within "users" then you can use Method "Elements" instead of "Element". The "Element" method will return first element and "Elements" method will return IEnumerable of XElement.

Answer (score -1):

It throws a `NullReferenceException` because, apparently, there is no "order" element in your document and therefore, `doc.Element("order")` returns null.

Comment: -1. Not really - Daniel adds order (as child of user). The search is just wrong.

Comment: " there is no 'order'" statement is wrong - check out `.Add(user);` - user contains order as immediate child. The problem is "order" element is not immediate child of the root element and hence can't be found by `Element` function on the root.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: If there was an "order" element, then `doc.Element("order")` wouldn't have returned null. Ergo, there is no "order" element. Comprendo?

Comment: Yes, there is not "order" element as immediate child of the `doc` (there is only one child "orders" and `doc.Element("orders")` is the only call to return non-null). But the question is not about it (at least as I read it) - it is about why newly added "order" element can't be found. "order" can be found by doc.Element("orders").Element("user").Element("order") thus proving it is in the document.